# Get NavigationController Stack of tabbarItem in a tabbarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to get the list of `UIViewControllers` i.e `UINavigationController` stack at particular index of tabbaritem in `UITabBarController`. 
Please ellaborate ..! 
Please guys join hands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSArray *arrControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
for(UIViewController *viewController in arrControllers)
{
   if([viewController isKIndOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
   {
     //NavigationController
     UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
     NSLog(@"%@",navCtrl.viewControllers);
   }
   else
   {
     // view controller
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the callback of [UITabBarControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3adidSelectViewController%3a) if you want to check this when a tab is changed:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    //if you're using navigationController
    UINavigationController *navC=(UINavigationController *)viewController;
    NSArray *arrayVc=navC.viewControllers;
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayVc);
}
```